# ASP.NET MVC 3: can I combine C# Razor Views with F# Controllers?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, f#, razor

I figure this is a straight forward question, and I think there is a good chance the answer is "yes" (while mixed-language projects are generally not possible, it seems to me that the View Engine gets special treatment). I know I could also try this out pretty easily myself, but for the record, and to save myself some time, I'd like to know if this combination is possible (I've not used ASP.NET MVC or Razor myself yet, I'm considering options for a new project at work).

**Edit:** I am particularly interested in whether this combination is possible within a *single* project. Or more specifically whether there are any feature losses using this combination (even if the two project setup is the way to go).

Comment: I'm going to guess No, but that might be more a function of the IDE than MVC.

Comment: Stephen, I've done this as Tomas has described--in separate projects--and it works well.

Comment: @Daniel - do you know if  there are any feature loses using this approach (like my concern raised in my comment to Tomas)?

Comment: @Stephen: I haven't done anything too complicated, but I haven't noticed if there are missing features--seems to do everything I want just fine. I think the auto-compile feature you mentioned works for Views, but not for controllers. That hasn't been an issue for me.

Comment: @Stephen: I loathe the current state of web development, but this is the best setup (MVC3 + C# views/F# controllers) I've ever used.

Comment: @Daniel - I believe you and share your opinion! Regardless of whether I can do a single project setup, I think I am going to go with this. WebForms suck. Grails is pretty nice (and taught me MVC), but can be troublesome (blackbox / dynamic issues). I'm sure C# would be fine in MVC for controllers, etc. but F# is just too compelling even if I do lose a couple framework or Visual Studio features. Note that there is another option that I am just not willing to invest in right now: zero server-side views, controllers are mere JSON webservices, all view work done on client using something like YUI

Comment: @Stephen: Have you looked at WebSharper?

Comment: @Daniel - I haven't, but I actually enjoy Javascript / jQuery a lot on the client side (HTML / DOM is so dynamic anyways, I am not convinced F# -> Javascript will buy me much... but I am ignorant here so certainly could be wrong, also I am scarred by WebForms so as to be skeptical of any high-level server-side abstraction of the client).

Comment: @Stephen: From what I've read, WebSharper is pretty efficient, but there's something to be said for MVC's bare-metal approach. It avoids mystery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can definitely mix a C# Razor code with F# controllers. It may be possible to do this in a single project (by modifying the web project to use F#). An easier alternative is to create a standard C# Razor Web project and a separate F# project (containing model and controller code).

I created a [Visual Studio template](http://tomasp.net/files/FSharpEmptyWeb.vsix) that allows you to do exactly this.

Unfortunatelly, the template is not yet available on Visual Studio Gallery (so you cannot see it from "Online Templates" tab in "New Project" dialog). There is some issue with their upload mechanism, that I'm trying to resolve, so it should hopefully appear there soon. There are also several ASP.NET MVC templates by Daniel Mohl on Visual Studio Gallery, but I'm not sure if any of them uses Razor.

Comment: Cool - I will definitely consider the two project approach using your template. But I am also interested in doing this within a single project: I'm not sure what the deal is with ASP.NET MVC, but when I used to do traditional ASP.NET WebForms development, a great features was per-page compilation so I could modify the view or "page behind", save, and reload the page with page dll automatically compiled and deployed dynamically into my running app. If MVC even has  that feature, I wonder if I'd lose it by using the two project solution...

Comment: oops, I get a 404 trying to access the link to your Visual Studio template.

Comment: @Stephen - I posted a wrong link. It should work now (http://tomasp.net/files/FSharpEmptyWeb.vsix).

Comment: @Stephen - When using two projects, you need to explicitly recompile the project. I'm not quite MVC expert, but I don't think it supports per-page compilation (mainly because there is no concept of "page"). It can just pick changes in the view (Razor) file. But I may be wrong... I liked this too - but apparently, web projects are mostly created as compiled these days (I think), but I don't quite understand why.